# Regular expression that recognises 3.1 and 3. as well as .1 as double

Tags: c++, regex, qregexp

What is the right regular expression to identify a floating point number such that only the decimal point and one number is required.

```
re = QRegExp("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+");
if (re.exactMatch(s))
    std::cout<< "Double"<<std::endl;
```

This code identifies `3.1` and `.1` as double but not `3.`. The trouble is, that if I make the second number block optional (replacing `+` with a `*`) then `.` would also be a double. How can I fix that?

I use Qts regular expression library, but I guess `std::regex` would work the same.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/6y0dn5/1

Comment: @WiktorStribizew that would also catch integers which shouldn't be: 3 is not a double (although not stated in my question)

Comment: Trying to solve a problem using regular expression just means that you now have two problems

Comment: It is even easier then, remove the optional group - https://regex101.com/r/bcU1fT/1